# How do I add multiple module directories in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I'm working on a Zend project where there is a need to make it easily extendable. Having considered various options, I think it would work best if these extensions used the same MVC structure as generic Zend modules but were grouped together in a seperate folder away from the core modules.

So the structure I would ideally like would be something like:

```
application
  configs
  core
    module1
    module2
  extensions
    extensionModule1
    extensionModule2
```

Then with this structure I'd like urls such as `module1/controller/action` and `extensionModule1/controller/action` to both work at the same time.

So is it possible to setup multiple module directories for the router to look in?

If this isn't possible, then any suggestions of another way to implement extensions that use MVC and are seperate from the core part of the site would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your application.ini do

> ```
> resources.frontController.moduleDirectory[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/core"
> resources.frontController.moduleDirectory[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/extensions"
> resources.modules = true;
> ```

ZF will look in both the directories and will consider all there sub directories as modules.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I thought it might be something like that but couldn't find any documentation on it. Thanks.